# Can I format git reflog to show when the reference pointed to each commit?

Tags: git

The documentation for [git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) mentions that

> git reflog show accepts any of the options accepted by git log.

and so I can do fancy formatting like this:

```
git reflog --format='%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d%Creset - %Cgreen%an%Creset, %Cblue%ar%Creset : %s' -30
```

[image: git reflog terminal screen capture]

The dates shown are for the commits that the reference pointed to. Is it possible to instead show when the reference was switched to point thus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git reflog` is displaying the content of `.git/logs` and you have the timestamp in there next to the commit info.

You can use the date format to the display the switch time

```
git reflog --date=iso
```

If you wish to see the original value as stored in the log file use the `raw format`. you can use this if you wish to modify it to a different date format

```
git reflog --date=raw
```